# Replace a line in File

Tags: java, file

I am trying to replace a line Number 3 of text in this File but unable to update proper line:

```
 ENTITY test_labelOperation IS
generic (
    NO_OF_COLS  : integer := 640;// This is 3rd line and replace should be look like NO_OF_RECTGlE=100;
    NO_OF_ROWS  : integer := 480; 
    NO_BITS_CC  : integer := 10;
    DATA_WORD : integer :=8; 
    CODE_WIDTH :integer :=9
    );
END test_labelOperation;
```

Here is the Code that I am trying:

```
  RandomAccessFile raf=new RandomAccessFile(absoluteFile,"rw");
  int lineCount=0;
  while(raf.read()!=-1) {
      String s=raf.readLine();
      //System.out.println(s);
      String stAry[];
      lineCount++;
      if (lineCount==3) {
         System.out.println(s);
         stAry=s.split("=",2);
         stAry[0]="NO_OF_RECTGlE";
         stary[1]=100+";";                        
         String str=Arrays.toString(stAry);
         byte []byt=str.getBytes();
         raf.write(byt);

         }
      }
```

Comment: When you stepped through it with the debugger, what happened at line 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the problem is in the fact that you read the 3rd line first, which moves the file pointer to the END of that line. So then, when you do `raf.write(byt)` you write to the end of that line, as opposed to over-the-top of the line.

You need to remember the position before you start reading 3rd line, using `raf.position()`, and then do `raf.seek(oldPosition)` before writing...

But I really don't recommend you do it this way. It's not the same as replacing a bit of text in an editor. The replace string has to be exactly of the same length as the string being replaced, otherwise you will end up with garbage in your file. If the replacement string is longer, then you'll have no choice but to rewrite the whole file from scratch.

I would strongly suggest you consider simply reading in all lines, replacing the third line and then overwriting the whole file over-the-top of the old one. It'll be easier to implement, and more robust.

Here's an example using the [Apache commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) for simplicity:

```
List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(file);
lines.set(2, "NO_OF_RECTGlE=100;");
FileUtils.writeLines(file, lines);
```